# how to get html2canvas working in ie8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas, flashcanvas

I am trying to run this simple `html2canvas` code. It work great in `Chrome, IE9, Firefox`. But is not working in `IE8`

Code:

```
html2canvas($(#section), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {            
            var img = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Home/SaveDiv",
                data: "{'imageData': '" + img + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');

                }
            });
        }
        });
```

Is there a way I can get it working in `IE8`. I have heard about `flashcanvas` which I am not sure on how to use it.

> Else, is there any other way I can capture `<div>` element in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because html2canvas requires IE9 or higher, as stated [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas).

Comment: recommend an alternative? and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a polyfill: [heres a canvas one](http://html5please.com/#canvas)

Comment: can u please explain how do i use one of the polyfills with respect to my code.